# chromium - google maps issue

Tags: chrome

I've been having issues with chromium lately on funtoo / gentoo.  I believe it started since version 55 (now I'm running 57).  When navigating to google maps, the page becomes unresponsive.  I cannot scroll, the input boxes and other elements go from having a nice grey shading to make it appear 3-dimensional to black.

I have no issues with firefox.  I suspect there is some sort of X11 issue going on, but I don't see anything in the logs or dmesg.

Oddly enough, google maps is the only site I can reproduce this issue on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not the best solution, but try deactivating "Use hardware acceleration when available" in Chromium advanced settings. If you have found a better solution, please let me know.

I'm experiencing the same issues since a few weeks. It's not only Google Maps in Chromium but also my 3D accelerated Virtual Box VMs (freezing randomly after 10-30 minutes). My guess: buggy graphic card driver (Radeon R9 380 / amdgpu).